# Session Tracker in facebook

Tags: android, facebook, session

I am integrating android app with Facebook. I am fetching user info and posting in user's account. Before somedays i was reading one tutorial, in which there was a code for SessionTracker. I dont know why it used?

I tried to search it but couldn't find anything useful. is there documentation available for this?

this is code for it.

```
SessionTracker mSessionTracker = new SessionTracker(getBaseContext(), new StatusCallback() {

        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        }
    }, null, false);
```

What is session tracker? why it used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SessionTracker is used for tracking the active session.
[SessionTracker](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/internal/SessionTracker.java)

But it should not be used on any where. SessionTracker is only used for other packages within the Facebook SDK for Android. Also have a look on the following links(specially the answers):
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338544/facebook-sdk-3-sesion-re-log-in-issue)
and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328148/how-to-programmatically-logout-from-facebook-sdk-3-0-without-using-facebook-logi)

Comment: then whts difference between sessionTracker and getActiveSession().

Comment: getActiveSession() is a method from which we can find the current active Session, but the sessionTracker is a class where there is various methods to track down the Session. Moreover the sessionTracker is an internal level api, suggested not to use, whereas getActiveSession() is the suggested api to use for getting the active session; the functionality of this two are not same, so they can not be compared on common base.

Comment: is there documentation for SessionTracker. So i can know what are the things possible with this, in case if i need it in future.

Comment: As its an internal level api, so i do not think there will be any documentation on publicly. The only doc we can find is the https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/internal/SessionTracker.java
But again Please don not use SessionTracker, i am prety sure what you want to achieve, can be done by the supported api rather than the SessionTracker.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help and suggestion. i will keep this in mind.